# Get JetBrains Rider to copy config files to output when running XUnit

Tags: xunit, appsettings, rider

I have created an Integration test for my asp.net core 2.1 web api using the TestServer.
Test works when I run "dotnet test" but in JetBrains Rider running XUnit 2.3.1 it all fails because the apsetting.json are not copied to output.

I have looked in Riders setting but I can't find a way to make it copy the settings files.

Answer (score 4):

In the context menu of file in SolutionExplorer open Properties
[image]

Comment: That is already set and dotnet test are copying all the files to output

Comment: What is the root of the problem? Is it that build doesn't copy the json file?

Comment: The problem is that riders testrunner does not copy configurations files to output

Comment: Why should test-runner copy anything? Does build or rebuild copy files?